# Algo to check if a web page content changed significantly

Tags: c#, web-crawler, diff

I need to systematically and programmatically detect when a large number of web pages content change significantly.

Basically I would say if a certain percentage of content changed is above a predefined threshold.

I need to do it often, so to limit processing time I need an optimized way of doing it.

I never did anything like that, but I guess there are some algorithm already developed, maybe some libraries, to do so?

Since it involves keeping a copy of the page, I am wondering if there's a way of zipping the html, or crunch it some way to reduce the size and still be able to compare it with new versions.

Anyone has faced the same problem in the past and could give me advice?

Comment: store a series of n byte hashes, if x amount differ ....

Comment: in that thread they mention levenshtein distance, I have used that algo in the past performance are horrible, it's very slow

Comment: @MaxFavilli that was just the first duplicate I found. There were other too: 1334725, 10750243...